# htaccess to nginx rewrite issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

In my code I am trying to convert Apache `.htaccess` into `Nginx` using online convertor. I even edited this file `etc/nginx/conf.d/domainname.conf` but the rewrite URLS won't work. I have two htaccess files, one of which used in root folder and the second one used in administration folder of my script.

Here is the root's htaccess file content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ index.php?slug=$1
```

htaccess converted code for Nginx

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /index.php?slug=$1;
  rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ /index.php?slug=$1;
}
```

Here is the administration folder htaccess file content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L,R=301]
```

Administration folder htaccess converted code for Nginx

```
location /administration {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$0.php break;
  }
  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1.php redirect;
}
```

I pasted the converted content into domainname.conf (domainname is my domain) and restart the ngnix but it won't work at all. I don't know whether my converted code is accurate or not or any thing else I am missing through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply edit the file i.e. `etc/nginx/conf.d/yourdomain.tld.conf` and look for the following code like this:

```
#location / {
#Uncomment 3 lines and set your rules here!
#}
```

You need to un-comment these 3 lines of code or paste this code instead:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /index.php?slug=$1;
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ /index.php?slug=$1;
    }
}

location /administration/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
}
```

Then you must require to restart `Nginx`, if restarted without any errors it will work accurately otherwise `Nginx` will stop working, this step is important.